# Passing byte array to Javascript inside QTWebView from QT C++ code

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I wish to take a file from the filesystem and pass it to a Web View hosted javascript that is loaded from a remote server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Passed it as a Base64 Encoded String.